# Existence of a vector whose norm is 1 in a Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Given a finite dimensional Banach space *V* over reals, I have to show that there exists $v \in V$ such that $\|v\|=1$

At first, I thought that there's an identity element *I* in *V*.

And $\|I\|=1$.

But then I think it is not necesarily true all the time.

So now I'm thinking about constructing a Cauchy sequence converging to *v* while its norm converges to 1.

Or can I just say that we can arbitrarily choose such vector by manipulating its basis?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider any non-zero normed vector space. Take a nonzero $w$ and define $v = w/\|w\|$. By the properties of a norm  $\|v\| = \|w\|/\|w\|$.

Comment: Thanks! :) Have a nice day!

Comment: You need the condition that $V$ has positive dimension. The zero-dimensional Banach space has only one vector, and its norm is zero.

Answer (score 1):

if $x \in V$ is non-zero then $||x|| \gt 0$, so set:
$$
x' = \frac{x}{||x||}
$$
it is now evident that $||x'|| = 1$

Comment: Can't believe I couldn't see this.. lol Thanks! Have a nice day!

Comment: we all have 'blind spots' occasionally! even here Qiaochu's point is a subtlety i didn't think about. the good news is that we can learn useful things about the "psychological" side of problem-solving from  such experiences.all the best with your studies!